# Anchoring/Aligning TextBlock in Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas

I've these in canvas:

```
<Canvas>
    <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=uc}" 
            Y1="{Binding FirstPoint}" Y2="{Binding FirstPoint}"
            Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstPoint}" />

    <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=uc}" 
            Y1="{Binding SecondPoint}" Y2="{Binding SecondPoint}"
            Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondPoint}"/>
</Canvas>
```

I want the first `TextBlock` to appear to the right of the first `Line` and the second one to the right of second `Line`.

**EDIT**

`Canvas.Bottom="{Binding FirstPoint/SecondPoint}"` and `Canvas.Right="0"` places those on top of the line BUT I want them to be centered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Canvas.Top` and adjust the final position with a negative vertical `Margin`:

```
<TextBlock Canvas.Top="{Binding FirstPoint}" Margin="0,-9"
           Text="{Binding FirstPoint}" />
```

In order to make this independent of a specific exact vertical margin, use a Label with a large enough Margin and `VerticalContentAlignment` set to `Center`:

```
<Label Canvas.Top="{Binding FirstPoint}" Margin="0,-20"
       Content="{Binding FirstPoint}"
       VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well since WPF binding doesn't allow mathematical operations in binding. So you can define  a value converter and use it to center your textboxes.

```
 public class HalfValueConverter : IValueConverter
 {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var actual = (double) value;
        return actual / 2;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
```

And in yor XAML :

```
  <Canvas>
        <Canvas.Resources>
            <local:HalfValueConverter x:Key="HalfValueConverter"></local:HalfValueConverter>
        </Canvas.Resources>
        <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=uc}" 
              Y1="{Binding FirstPoint}" Y2="{Binding FirstPoint}" Name="Line1"
              Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstPoint}" Canvas.Top="{Binding FirstPoint}" Margin="0,-20"
                   Canvas.Left="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=Line1,Converter={StaticResource HalfValueConverter}}"/>

        <Line X1="0" X2="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=uc}" 
              Y1="{Binding SecondPoint}" Y2="{Binding SecondPoint}" Name="Line2"
              Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SecondPoint}" Canvas.Top="{Binding SecondPoint}" Margin="0,-20" 
                   Canvas.Left="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=Line2,Converter={StaticResource HalfValueConverter}}"/>
    </Canvas>
```

[image: Output]

Comment: That's a lot! I think @Clemens way is simpler. Thanks a lot for your answer, hope it'll help someone someday for some other situation.